# Skip a stage in Jenkins pipeline Globally

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 200+ Jenkinsfile which we have created in a hurry. We did not know about shared libraries at that time. Now we need to skip one of the stages from all the Jobs. Stage name is common in all the Jenkinsfile.

For eg, lets call that stage **FOOSTAGE**. Is there a way I can depreciate or skip this stage from all the jobs, without changing jenkinsfile. We cannot afford to edit the files as we are short on time.

We have declarative pipeline and My requirement is very simple. I am thinking of it as a when command defined globally for this particular stage **FOOSTAGE**.